# React not building properly. Probably something with function components (?)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, jsx, react-component

My component works just fine, but my problem is the building. Is there a special loader I need to make this work?

I have a function component like this, which is using a component called `<Tabs>`. This component `<Tabs>` is coming from a npm module. And the documentation is saying that I should add an object like tabsContent as child of `<Tabs>`

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const tabsData = [
    { title: 'One title' key: 'firstKey' },
    { title: 'Another title', key: 'secondKey' },
  ];

  const tabsContent = {
    firstKey: () => <FirstComponent />,
    secondKey: () => <SecondComponent />,
  };

  return (
    <Tabs data={tabsData}>
      {tabsContent}
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

The build is giving me an error when I have these `<FirstCompoent />` and `<SecondCompoent />`, which is also finction-components, but it works when I exchange these with regular `<div>`'s. Is there some reason for that? The code is running as expected. The error I get is something like this from the build:

```
| var ParentComponent = function ParentComponent((_temp2 = (_temp = _ref, _ref3 = <FirstCompoent></FirstCompoent>, _temp), _ref4 = <SecondCompoent></SecondCompoent>, _tem
p2)) {
|   var _temp, _ref3, _temp2, _ref4;
```

Comment: If I'm getting this right, `tabsContent` is not a valid react children, it's an object. To render component you have to return a valid render component, like `{tabsContent.firstKey}`

Comment: Yes, that is corrcet. I forgot to tell you guys that <Tabs> is a component that takes this tabsContent form in as childs. I am just using a finish <Tabs> component where the documentation said I should have an object like tabsContent as a child. I am sorry for that. I added that to my question.

Comment: can you define "not working"?

Comment: @DanO, I tried to reformulate myself. With "not working" I meant that the build is giving me the error message which is in the question.

Comment: Please be more specific, and share what the error is. Can you also share the entirety of your `ParentComponent` code so it is easier to tell what "tabs" component you're importing?

Comment: Also, it's not a good practice to return anything but a valid react child from React function component

Comment: @blits the <FirstComponent /> and <SecondComponent /> are valid functional react components. All the code are working. It is only the building that fails.